# GitHub Pages redirection to custom name : not responsive

Tags: mobile, redirect, github-pages, responsive

I have a static website hosted on GitHub Pages that you can see here : https://maxtison.github.io/stephanietison/

When I access this URL via mobile, it works perfectly fine.

BUT, when I access to http://stephanietison.com via mobile, which redirects to the GitHub Page above, the responsive part seems broken.

Any idea how I could resolve this problem ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

I found adding this meta tag to be the solution.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

I was reading about it here [GitHub Pages redirection to custom name : not responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416683/github-pages-redirection-to-custom-name-not-responsive)

Comment: Didn't you notice that he has this meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />` in his html already?